# Firebase: Database not updating

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am using Firebase for the first time in Android studio.  I connected using android assistant and I want to add a food name, category and best before date. When I click add food button nothing is updating. I have updated the read write rules to true and the assistant says the database is connected.
Am I missing a connection somewhere?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextName;
Button buttonAdd;
Spinner spinnerCategory;
EditText editTextDate;

DatabaseReference databaseFood;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseFood = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Food");

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddFood);
    spinnerCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
    editTextDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);


    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}

private void addArtist(){
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String genre = spinnerCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

        String id = databaseFood.push().getKey();

        Food food = new Food(id, name, genre);


        databaseFood.child(id).setValue(food);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Food added to Fridge.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "You should enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

I also added a java class called Food

```
public class Food {

String foodId;
String foodName;
String foodCategory;

public  Food(){

}

public Food(String foodId, String foodName, String foodCategory) {
    this.foodId = foodId;
    this.foodName = foodName;
    this.foodCategory = foodCategory;
}

public String getFoodId() {
    return foodId;
}

public String getFoodName() {
    return foodName;
}

public String getFoodCategory() {
    return foodCategory;
}

}
```

Comment: Sems to be you do not call method where you update DB from `onClick` method.

Comment: I added this in and still nothing updates

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
databaseFood = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Food").push();

private void addArtist(){
String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
String genre = spinnerCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

databaseFood.child("name").setValue(name);
databaseFood.child("genre").setValue(genre);
 }}
```

that way you have in the database:

```
  Food:{
   pushrandomid:{
       name: nuggets
       genre: chicken
         }
      }
```

Also add setters in the class, click `alt`+`ins` and add setters

Your database should be like this:

[image: database sample]

Comment: would this go in the OnCreate method?

Comment: setValues can go inside `private void addArtist(){` and the `databaseFood = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Food").push();` can go inside onCreate. The same as you have done just change accordingly. But you may have to do this `setValue(food.getFoodName())`

Comment: still nothing happens to the database

Comment: I wrote "databaseFood.child("name").setValue(name);
databaseFood.child("genre").setValue(genre);" under private void add food.

in my database there is nothing at all it shows no text

Comment: is there a root node in the database? You mean under `addArtist` , there is no `private void add food` in the code above

Comment: no there is nothing in the database . I included an image in the question to explain what i mean

Sorry i meant under private void addArtist()

Comment: yes there should be a root node there by default, not sure why maybe your not connected right..

Comment: i connected using the assistant.. should i restart and try to connect manually?

Comment: I  have updated, you dont have root node, go to tools>firebase>database>then connect to database. I think you are connected to firebase but not the database

Comment: i added another image .. i think it means i am connected?

Comment: try to connect again the the database, in a testing project a root node should be there by default.. maybe you entered something wrong

Comment: i have an idea now that maybe its got to do with the authentication?

Comment: i still didnt find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the following answer will help to solve all the problems and it provides some efficient way to do this action. ;-)

1. Recreate your Food class as follows:-

.

```
public class Foods {                                                             
String foodName;
String foodCategory;

public  Food(){

}

public Food(String foodName, String foodCategory) {
    this.foodName = foodName;
    this.foodCategory = foodCategory;
}

public String getFoodName() {
    return foodName;
}

public String getFoodCategory() {
    return foodCategory;
}
```

2. Format the main code as follows.

.

```
public class MainAcivity extends AppCompactActivity {
EditText editTextName;
Button buttonAdd;
Spinner spinnerCategory;
EditText editTextDate;                                                
DatabaseReference databaseFood;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String category = spinnerCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadFoodData();

        }
    });

}


Private void uploadFoodData(){
    databaseFood = FirebaseDataBase.getInstance.getReference();
    String id = databaseFood.push().getKey();
    Foods food = new Foods(name, category);
    databaseFood.child(id).setValue(food);
}
```

3. Just copy and paste the code accordingly.